# QGIS Essen Size Scale Field new location

Tags: qgis

Just updated to QGIS Essen 2.14.1

I want to scale markers based on a field in the layer's attribute table. In the previous version of QGIS I had installed, under layer properties->style -> graduated ->advanced, there was an option called Size-Scale-Field. In this Essen, this not longer is located here.

Looking for direction on how to scale markers according to field values in QGIS 2.14.1

Answer (score 0):

Is this under the `Method` option now?

[image: Layer Properties window screenshot - "Method" highlighted under "Style"]